# Passing an Arduino Variable to JS

Tags: javascript, html, arduino

This may be a very simple question for someone out there.

Say I have an int Arduino vairble:

```
int sensorData = analogRead(sensorPin);
```

How would I be able to pass that as a JS variable?

```
client.println("<script> var dat = sensorData </script>"); // this is what I have tried
```

For more context, I am trying to pass the variable to update a webpage heading; which does work if I pass in a JS variable, but not an Arduino one:

```
client.println("<h1 id=\"sensorData\"> %SENSORDATA% </h1>");
client.println("document.getElementById(\"sensorData\").innerHTML = dat");
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The client class has the [`print`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/ClientPrint) and [`printLn`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/ClientPrintln) functions.

so you should be able to split it up and do something like:

```
client.print("<h1 id=\"sensorData\"> ");
client.print(sensorData);
client.println(" </h1>");
```

Comment: `client.print("<script> var dat = ") ; client.print (sensorData); ...` should work as well, if you really want/need it. (see the difference?)

Comment: Worked a treat. Thank you.